# Retrieve data from mysql db to textfield

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm trying to implement a payroll system and got some issues with it. The program needs to be able retrieve data from mysql db to jtextfield.

when I try to search I get and error saying "com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException. You have an error in your SQL systax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"

```
package AppPackage;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AllowanceGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

public AllowanceGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    conn=MySQLConnect.ConnectDb();
}                                 

private void SearchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


    try {
        String sql = "SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Designation,BasicSalary FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE EmployeeID =?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,EmployeeIDSearchField.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) { 
        EmployeeIDField.setText(rs.getString("EmployeeID"));
        FirstNameField.setText(rs.getString("FirstName"));
        LasNameField.setText(rs.getString("LastName"));
        DesignationField.setText(rs.getString("Designation"));
        BasicSalaryField.setText(rs.getString("BasicSalary"));



    }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}}
```

my db connection is as below;

package AppPackage;

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MySQLConnect {
Connection conn = null;
public static Connection ConnectDb(){

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://Localhost/easypay","root","");
    return conn;
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    return null;

    }
}
}
```

can anybody please help me with this code?

Comment: What is the specific problem? What have you tried? Is there an error?

Comment: when I try to search I get and error saying "com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException. You have an error in your SQL systax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the error.

```
private void SearchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


    try {
        String sql = "SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Designation,BasicSalary FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE EmployeeID =?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,EmployeeIDSearchField.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()) { 
        String ID = rs.getString("EmployeeID");
        EmployeeIDField.setText(ID);
        String FN = rs.getString("FirstName");
        FirstNameField.setText(FN);
        String LN = rs.getString("LastName");
        LasNameField.setText(LN);
        String Des = rs.getString("Designation");
        DesignationField.setText(Des);
        String BS = rs.getString("BasicSalary");
        BasicSalaryField.setText(BS);

    }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

you are doing

```
   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);// Prepare this sql query for me
    pst.setString(1,EmployeeIDSearchField.getText());// Attach this value as first parameter
    rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);// IGNORE EVERYTHING, Execute this query
```

you should do `pst.executeQuery();` on the third line instead.

**EDIT**

Totally read over the fact it was a select. you should just do executeQuery without the string query.
P.s. for greater speed use column indexes(integers) instead of column names in your rs.next() loop.

Comment: now it says can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs

Comment: made the edits but still not showing the outputs in the fields when I click search button. I don't see the error anymore thought.

Comment: Does your query yield results? Can you print them to System.out? if your query returns no results, it won't do anything obviously